# Floating Label with Input Text - Label is touching to bottom border of input in android using in react native

Tags: android, react-native, floating

I have implemented floating label  with input item. below is My Code and attached a screen shot. Floating label is working fine in iphone but in android floating label is touching bottom border while using react native

```
<Item floatingLabel style={styles.floatInput}>
            <Label style={styles.lbl}>Enter Your Mobile Number</Label>
            <Input
              style={styles.inputcolor}
              ref="Mobile"
              keyboardType="numeric"
              onChangeText={text => {
                this.checkSetMobile(text)
              }}
              value={this.state.Mobile}
            />
              <Icon style={{color:AppColors.colors.main_color}} name="md-call" />
          </Item>

      lbl: {
        paddingTop: Platform.OS === "ios" ? undefined : 5 ,
        paddingBottom: Platform.OS === "ios" ? undefined : 5 ,
        marginBottom: 5,

      },
      inputcolor: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingBottom:5,
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently I have work done by this line in floating label and it solved my problem

```
paddingTop: Platform.OS === "ios" ? undefined : -15 ,
```